# NSIncrementalStore - Using local and remote data

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, core-data, nspersistentstore

I've read a few articles about `NSIncrementalStore` and I'm still confused about the whole concept. In this [**post**](http://sealedabstract.com/code/nsincrementalstore-the-future-of-web-services-in-ios-mac-os-x/) we can read that:

> Essentially you can now create a custom subclass of `NSPersistentStore`,
>   so that instead of your `NSFetchRequest` hitting a local SQLite
>   database, it runs a method you define that can do something arbitrary
>   to return results (like make a network request).

Up to this point I thought that NSIncrementalStore was **a perfect solution for accessing remote data and saving/caching it locally**. Now, I deduce that it's a solution only for accessing remote data.

If I am right I will be thankful for any piece of advice on some work-around.
If I am wrong, where is the magic and how to implement it ? Every post/article/tutorial on NSIncrementalStore shows how easily it is to pull data from server but none of them has given even a single clue about caching things for offline viewing.

Answering, let's consider a common scenario that an app is supposed to download some data from the Internet, display it and save locally so that users may use the app offline.

Also, I am not committed to use NSIncrementalStore or something. I am just looking for the best solution and this class was described as one by some of the best experts in this field.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused too for about 4 or 5 hours :)
So. 
Your inherited class of NSPersistentStore is "representation" of your remote data storage.

So, for the **accessing remote data and saving/caching it locally** you need to do the following

1) Create subclass of NSPersistentStore and setup it.

Like that:

`YOURIncrementalStore *incrementalStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:[YOURIncrementalStore type] configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&error];`

where coordinator your main NSPersistentStoreCoordinator

2) Then, you need other NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, that will "coordinate local representation(incrementalStore) and context of the external storage" and provide your local storage representaton (like SQLite DB URL) to it:

`[incrementalStore.backingPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]`

But dont forget, that your new persistent store must know all your **previous** local state. So options dict will be:

`NSDictionary *options = @{ NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                             NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES }`

So, imho, i understand all internal work this way:

You request some data from external API. Parse it, then save to the context of your backingPersistentStoreCoordinator, then merge to the main one. So the states of all the contexts will be equal.

All of the previous text is based on work with AFIncrementalStore workaround.

My code to implement AFIncrementalStore with MagicalRecord:

```
  - (void)addMRAndAFIS {
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStack];

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSPersistentStore urlForStoreName:[MagicalRecord defaultStoreName]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator defaultStoreCoordinator];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *arr = coordinator.persistentStores;
    AFIncrementalStore *incrementalStore = (AFIncrementalStore*)[coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:[PTIncrementalStore type] configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&error];

    NSDictionary *options = @{ NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                         NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES };
    arr = coordinator.persistentStores;
    if (![incrementalStore.backingPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
      NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      abort();
    }
  }
```

If we need to discuss the easiest way, you need just subclass NSIncrementalStore, setup it correctly(like i wrote), parse data, then create some context, save date to it, then save it and merge to parent context.

So you will have 2 Stores and 2 contexts, and 1 StoreCoordinator.

If i've made mistake somewhere, please refer to it.

ALSO, try: https://gist.github.com/stevederico/5316737

Comment: I've already started implementing my own subclass. I will post it soon as opensource, stay tuned. :D

Comment: So what? Do you get what you want?

Comment: I'm still doing it but I'll finish soon. It is going to be available on my github - github.com/wczekalski

Comment: Hello guys. If I understood right afincrementalstore allows as to pull data from the server and parse it to the entity. Correct me as well

Comment: I have created this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796459/automatically-filling-coredata-model-with-json-data-from-remote-rest-server) that is connected to pull and parse data from the server to core data. So can i use incrementalstore for it?

Comment: You don't need to use `NSSQLiteStoreType` for `backingPersistentStoreCoordinator`. You can use `NSInMemoryStoreType` and don't create file for that.